# insert line break in the message in coffee script

Tags: coffeescript

i have a web app written in nodes/coffeescript, one of the coffee script code read data out of db then display message to the browser, it's a long message, i want to break it down by lines, but cannot get the line break work correctly, i tried:

```
<br>
\n
\n\n
```

neither of them works, here is my message in coffee script:

```
message = 'OK<br>'
message += 'last update at 12PM\n'
message += 'outdated\n\n'
```

callback null, {state: state, message: message}

thanks,

Comment: How is `message` being displayed? As a JS string, [`"\n"` works fine.](http://coffeescript.org/#try:alert%20%22Hello%5CnCoffeeScript!%22)

Comment: the message is included in a callback function,which will return to the front-end, and be displayed on browser

Comment: So you are displaying in HTML. [In that case `<br>` should work fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/Qzp26/) Your issue is not in your posted code.